# How can I insert a comma in a selected string?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

How can I use SQL to insert a comma into a selected string, so that `(2%10 NET30)` becomes `(2%10, NET30)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into *this* string? With `REPLACE`:

```
SQL> select replace('2%10 NET30', ' ', ', ') result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
-----------
2%10, NET30

SQL>
```

Other strings might require different approach.

Comment: Im getting this 2%10,,NET30. doble comma